# Memory issue in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, dealloc

Please help, I am really struggling with the memory leak issue. Here is my code

```
+ (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.itemArray removeAllObjects];  //0.8%
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &dataBase) == SQLITE_OK) //18.9%
    {
        NSString *sqlStr = @"select * from ItemTable order by Status_id asc, ReleaseDate desc";
        const char *sql = [sqlStr UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dataBase, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) { //25%
            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) { //46.3
                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                DataBaseClass *itemObj = [[DataBaseClass alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];  // 2.6%

                itemObj.itemID = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                itemObj.itemName = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,1)) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)] : nil;
                itemObj.availableIcon = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,2)) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 2)] : nil;
                itemObj.notAvialableIcon = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,3)) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,3)] : nil;
                itemObj.itemReleaseDate = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 4)) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 4)] : nil;
                itemObj.itemStatus = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,5)) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 5)] : nil;
                itemObj.itemModDate = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,6)) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 6)] : nil;
                itemObj.status_id = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 7);
                itemObj.availableLocalIconPath = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,8)) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 8)] : nil;
                itemObj.notAvialableLocalIconPath = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt,9)) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 9)] : nil;

                [appDelegate.itemArray addObject:itemObj];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
    }
    else
        sqlite3_close(dataBase); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
}
```

I am getting the memory leak at some lines in this code. No idea how to fix this. I am using ARC in my app. And I tracked this using Instruments tool in XCode in Zombie enabled mode. And also I mentioned the percentage of leaks happened in some lines. Please check the code and help please.

Answer (score 0):

If you're successful, sqlite3_finalize is called, but you never close your database.  Since you open it in this method as well, you should close it here too.  Remove the last 'else' and see what happens.